# C# - Loop input until EOF

Tags: c#, eof

This is my code to loop input until eof:

```
string input;
List<string> s = new List<string>();
while((input = Console.ReadLine()) != null && input != ""){
   input = Console.ReadLine();
   s.Add(input);

}

foreach(string h in s){
   Console.WriteLine(h);
}
```

The input keep looping each line until I pressed 'ctrl-z'. Each input is assigned into list s, but it seems that not all input assigned into list s.

output:

[image]

The output should be:

> a
>
> b
>
> c
>
> d

Thanks for help;

Comment: Because you're calling ReadLine twice for each loop iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were calling `Console.ReadLine()` twice for every loop.
The easy fix is to remove the second call.

```
string input;
List<string> s = new List<string>();
while((input = Console.ReadLine()) != null && input != ""){
   s.Add(input);
}

foreach(string h in s){
   Console.WriteLine(h);
}
```

You may as well write the while statement like this:

```
while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input = Console.ReadLine())){
        s.Add(input);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. It's really simple, I though the ReadLine in while statemen wouldn't be executed after input inside while.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the second readLine call should be enough.